# Warning: mysql_connect(): Host 'ip-X-X-X-X.ec2.internal' is blocked because of many connection errors

Tags: php, redhat, rhel7

I'm using following system:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1 (Maipo)
$ uname -a
Linux ip-X-X-X-X.ec2.internal 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 25 11:21:22 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ rpm -q php 
php-5.4.32-1.el7.remi.x86_64
$
```

and every now and then, I'm getting following error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Host 'ip-X-X-X-X.ec2.internal' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts' in /var/www/html/X/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1454
Error establishing a database connection
This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can't contact the database server at ip-X-X-X-X.ec2.internal. This could mean your host's database server is down.

Are you sure you have the correct username and password?
Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname?
Are you sure that the database server is running?
If you're unsure what these terms mean you should probably contact your host. If you still need help you can always visit the WordPress Support Forums.
```

... after I run `mysqladmin flush-hosts` error goes away.

My question is: What is exactly causing it? and what can I tweak to prevent this error from happening too often?